# iOS - Access output audio from background program

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, background, ipod

Scenario: My app is running in the background. An iPhone/iPad user launches the iPod app (or Pandora or another program that plays audio) on their device and starts playing music. My app detects that that music is now playing, and records or in some way does things with the current playing audio (like stream it to a server), all while still running in the background.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction in the SDK on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. And that is that.

Comment: Has anything changed with iOS 7/8?