# Is it possible to access speaker output in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add a feature to my app that will do something on the tempo of the songs being played in the default iOS music player. Is this possible? Does my app have access to the audio data output from another app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access raw iphone audio output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282919/is-it-possible-to-access-raw-iphone-audio-output)

Comment: Yeah, but that's from 2012. Thought maybe stuff has changed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. On iOS each app is in its own "sandbox" and the only way to get out of the sandbox is to have an app extension to the other app, which means that the app you want to change the music for has to be compatible for extensions to change the music and your app needs to have the extension. I do not think that any apps have that and the stock apps do not have that. So it is impossible to do that and get it accepted on the App Store.